# Delete Temporary Tables from Abandoned ALTER Query

Tags: mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

I had some big tables, where the running ALTER query timed out.

Is there a way to remove the temporary tables created by this ALTER query, as they are taking up a huge amount of storage.

I am on RDS.

Thanks